# Not able to create snmpv3 session using IPv6 address

Tags: perl, snmp, ipv6, net-snmp, snmpd

I am not able to create SNNMPv3 session in perl using IPv6 address .
I am using below SNMP API to create SNMPv3 session but it throws error during session creation . If anyone have any idea , please let me know .

```
($session,$error) = new SNMP::Session(DestHost => 'IPv6 address',
                             Version => 3,
                             RemotePort => 162,
                             SecEngineId => '80001f888001324def',
                             SecName => 'skohrs',
                             AuthProto => 'SHA',
                             AuthPass => 'PaSSWoRDPaSSWoRDPaSS',
                             PrivProto => 'DES',
                             PrivPass => 'PaSSWoRDPaSSWoRD',
                             SecLevel => 'authPriv');
}
```

Comment: What is the error? You must make sure the agent monitors at IP v6 addresses, or it will never respond.

Comment: Lex Li , i checked the net-snmp module , it seems that SNMP package doesn't support IPv6 . Please suggest if I am wrong .

Comment: Try changing the value of `DestHost` to `udp6:[::1]:162` (where `::1` is the actual address). The net-snmp library [does support IPv6](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/FAQ.html#How_do_I_specify_IPv__addresses_in_tools_command_line_arguments_), but I'm not sure if the same approach will work for the Perl bindings.

Comment: Thanks for your response .  Can you please confirm whether perl support snmpv3 + IPv6  fully.

Comment: No, I can't test right now. Try my suggestion and see if it works. Note that you have to enable IPv6 when you compile the net-snmp C library.

Comment: I have tried udp6:[ipv6_address], session creation is happening but i am not able to send trap . I am using perl package and not sure how to make it work .

Comment: @Ravi Create an [SNMP::TrapSession](https://metacpan.org/pod/SNMP#SNMP::TrapSession) and call its `trap` method, e.g. `my ($session, $error) = SNMP::TrapSession->new(...); $session->trap(...);` (By the way, the documentation is terrible so I'm not surprised you're having trouble!)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot   I have tried earlier snmpv3 session with IPv4 and i was able to send trap as well . However the real problem is when i changed address as udp6:[ipv6_address], session is getting created but i am not able to send trap with same api($session->trap) . So I am not sure how to make it work .. Please suggest . Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the SNMP.xs code, it doesn't appear that it supports IPv6.  You should look at [Net::SNMP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3A%3ASNMP) which does support both IPv4 and IPv6 address families.

Comment: Thanks Vince for your response . For Net::SNMP ,I found below information NOTE:                                                                                        ====================================================  This method can only be used when the version of the object is set to SNMPv2c. SNMPv2-Trap-PDUs are supported by SNMPv3, but require the sender of the message to be an authoritative SNMP engine which is not currently supported by the Net::SNMP module.

Comment: Here is link so i m doubtful whether it support SNMPv3 fully.  http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/lib/Net/SNMP.pm#snmpv2_trap()_-_send_a_SNMP_snmpV2-trap_to_the_remote_manager

Comment: Can you please let me know the api you have used to send snmpv3 trap

Answer (score 0):

[Net::SNMP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3A%3ASNMP) is a pure Perl module so install is easy and you can test for yourself.  I've used it with SNMPv3 and IPv6 and had no issues.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to pass EngineID while creating SNMPv3 session using Net::SNMP . I tried below    =========                             ($session,$error) = Net::SNMP->session (
                   -hostname =>  'IP',
                   -port => '162',
                   -version=> 'SNMPv3',
                   -domain => 'udp6';
                   -username=> 'skohrs';
                   -authpassword => 'PaSSWoRDPaSSWoRDPaSS',
                   -authprotocol => 'SHA',
                   -privpassword => 'PaSSWoRDPaSSWoRD';
                   -privprotocol => 'DES');====

Comment: Also Can you please let me know which API can be used to send SNMPv3 trap using Net::SNMP module .

Comment: Can you please let me know which API can be used to send SNMPv3 trap using Net::SNMP module